What does malware do?
When I was 6, I always thought what malware would do is over heat your computer and make your PC explode. But how does malware work anyway?
From 5 years old to 8, these were still my thoughts. Can you all read this and answer for me?
Today, I still don't know...

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is not a discussion forum, it is a question and answer site where we expect questions to have a clear problem that needs to be solved. Malware is simply software that acts in a way that is against the computer owners interests and software can operate in any numbers of ways.

Short answer, you can google the rest, malware is like a virus, but instead of it wanting to spread, it wants to collect information about your system and send it to the developers of that malware so they can sell your information. Malware is often programmed badly, which is why it usually slows down your system and/or internet. It is also possible that one infection can both be malware and a virus.
